# Get the current value in Selectpicker using jQuery in Codeigniter Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I was trying to do a DOM manipulation using the value of the selected option of the selectpicker. What i wanted was to get the value of the selectpicker `id="service_provider_select"` to get printed first.I change the option using the selectpicker and when i run the `console.log(input)`, every time I've got the `Dialog` as the printed value in the console.
How can I get the value for the recent selection?

**HTML**

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control item_select" id="service_provider_select" name="service_provider_select" data-size="5" data-live-search="true">
        <option value="">Select Sevice Provider</option>
        <option value="Dialog"> Dialog </option>
        <option value="Mobitel"> Mobitel </option>
        <option value="Airtel"> Airtel </option>
        <option value="Hutch"> Hutch </option>
</select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
      $(".selectpicker").selectpicker();

      $('#service_provider_select').on("click", function()
      {
         input = $('#service_provider_select').val();
         console.log(input);
      });
   });

   var input = "Dialog";

</script>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, what is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: @sauhardnc sorry for my bad english. I just wanted to get the value of the `<select class="selectpicker form-control item_select" id="service_provider_select">` to the `input` using jQuery. But i couldn't do that.

Comment: On `<select>` you should use `change` event instead of `click`, otherwise, your code looks right.

Comment: Thank you very much @sauhardnc. It worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a working snippet for your issue which seems to work for me, see if it works for you as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".selectpicker").selectpicker();

  // Fire event on change instead of on click
  $('#service_provider_select').on("change", function() {
    input = $('#service_provider_select').val();
    console.clear();
    console.log(input);
  });
});

var input = "Dialog";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker form-control item_select" id="service_provider_select" name="service_provider_select" data-size="5" data-live-search="true">
  <option value="">Select Sevice Provider</option>
  <option value="Dialog"> Dialog </option>
  <option value="Mobitel"> Mobitel </option>
  <option value="Airtel"> Airtel </option>
  <option value="Hutch"> Hutch </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Happy to help. :)